# For the simple linear regression model, show that the elements of the hat matrix $H$ are...

Tags: matrices, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

Need some help with this one.
For the simple linear regression model, show that the elements of the hat matrix $H$ are:
$h_{ij}=1/n + (x_i -\bar x)(x_j -\bar x)/S_{xx}$ and
$h_{ii}=1/n + (x_i -\bar x)^2/S_{xx}$
Please help me MathStack (Vancak), you are my only hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, recall that
$$
H= X(X'X)^{-1}X'=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\quad x_1 \\
1\quad x_2\\
:\quad : \\
1\quad x_n 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
\quad\frac{\sum x_i^2}{nS_{xx}}  \quad-\frac{\sum x_i}{nS_{xx}} \\
-\frac{n}{nS_{xx}} \quad \frac{n}{nS_{xx}}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \quad 1\quad 1 \quad ...\quad 1 \\
x_1 \quad x_2 \quad x_3 \quad
 \, ...\quad x_n\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So, basically just multiple and manipulate slightly the sums. For $h_{ii}$ you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961422/hat-matrix-with-simple-linear-regression), the transition to $h_{ij}$ should be straightforward.