# How do I prove the diagonal element of the hat matrix, $h_{ii}$ (leverage)

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, regression, linear-regression

Consider the simple linear regression model
$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \text{error}, i = 1,2,\ldots,n$

$h_{ij}$ denotes the $[i,j]$ element of the hat matrix.

How can I show that $h_{ii} = 1/n + (x_i - \bar{x})^2/S_{xx}$

$h_{ii}$ is the leverage but what kind of observation of $x_i$ would have the lowest/highest leverage?

Comment: I think you mean $h_{ii} = \frac{1}{n} + (x_i - \bar{x})^2/S_{xx}$ (not $h_{ij}$).

Comment: Given the above formula, you can easily see that values of $x_i$ that are "far" from the mean $\bar{x}$ will have high leverage.

Comment: yes! my mistake. I meant $h_{ii}$

Comment: One way to verify that identity is to explicitly compute $X(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top$ with $X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 \\ 1 & x_2 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & x_n\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410854/proof-about-the-diagonal-element-of-the-hat-matrix, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961422/hat-matrix-with-simple-linear-regression?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2653098/for-the-simple-linear-regression-model-show-that-the-elements-of-the-hat-matrix?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325504/leverage-in-simple-linear-regression