# How can I prove this equation in another way?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling

[image]

I want to prove equation 2.29b, but in a different way from whats given in the text. What theorems can I use to approach this?

(just in case, the book is Applied Linear Statistical Models, 5th Edition, Kutner)

Comment: Please use MathJax for the relevant parts of your question.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410854/proof-about-the-diagonal-element-of-the-hat-matrix, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1961422/hat-matrix-with-simple-linear-regression?noredirect=1&lq=1 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325504/leverage-in-simple-linear-regression?noredirect=1&lq=1.